Порядок выполнения функции
Использую в функции в качестве аргумента функцию у которой указываю аргумент
from log_v2 import t, l

l(t(r'C:\Test\'))

функция l()
import logging
from datetime_v8 import name, t

dirlog = r'C:\Test\log.txt'

def l(t, namefile=name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(dirlog)
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter())
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    logger.info('Скрипт {} начал работу'.format(namefile()))

    try:
        t()
    except ValueError as v:
        logger.error(v)
    except KeyboardInterrupt as k:
        logger.error('Исполнение прервано вручную')

    logger.info('Скрипт завершил работу'+'\n')


if __name__=="__l__":
    l(t, namefile)    



Подскажите почему при выполнении l(t(r'C:\Test\')) начинает исполняться функция t а не l и как правильно вызывать такого вида конструкции

а что вы ожидали? что бы вычислить l нужно вычислить t для начала.

У вас же во втором коде даже пример прямо приведён как вызывать: l(t, namefile). Хотя там тоже непонятно, откуда namefile взялось. И не называйте методы и переменные одной буквой. Давайте им нормальные имена.

Вы не передаете функцию t, вы ее выполняете!
Попробуйте так:
l(t) - Выполняется только l
l(t()) - Выполняется t, а потом результат t передается в l и выполняется l

Чтоб исправить проблему:
l(t(r'C:\Test\')) # Не правильно
l(t, r'C:\Test\') # Правильно

Функция l принимает 2 аргумента: функцию и название файла

Вы хотите передать аргумент в функцию t и не выполнить ее до l?

Здесь пример, в каком порядке вычисляются функции:

Например, для значения '-127' (это не число, а строка из 4 символов) мы получим постепенно

значит, результатом будет число 127.
